# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError in PowerManager

Tags: android, nosuchmethoderror, android-powermanager

I got the below error log and not sure how this could be fixed

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.PowerManager.isInteractive
    at com.example.myapp.app.ActivityLifecycleCallbackListener.onActivityPaused(ActivityLifecycleCallbackListener.java:131)
    at android.app.Application.dispatchActivityPaused(Application.java:217)
    at android.app.Activity.onPause(Activity.java:1295)
    at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onPause(FragmentActivity.java:384)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`isInteractive` id added in API level 20 as stated by [developer.android.com](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/PowerManager.html#isInteractive()).

You need to check the API level before call the method:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT_WATCH) {
    //isInteractive() call
}
```

Comment: I don't call this method at all in my code.. I suppose it been called by default in some scenario when the Activity goes to pause state.

Comment: The app with a package name `com.comcast` has a class named `ActivityLifecycleCallbackListener` that call `isInteractive` inside the method `onActivityPaused`.

Comment: yes you were right, this was a temporary code and I forgot about it. You answers seems to be right for users for face this issue. So I am going to accept the and